# Can't store images on Firebase - W/DynamiteModule: Failed to retrieve remote module version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm learning to program in Android by watching a series of tutorial to make a simple blog app in Android Studio with Firebase.

In this part of the tutorial, I did exactly the same as what was mentioned by using an ImageButton and EdiTexts for uploading to my Firebase Storage (Image with Title and description), but when I submit the image, this keeps charging indefinitely and the toast "*Posting to Blog...*" never ends and the image is not uploaded to my database.

I checked that I have changed the rules of my Firebase to public, both in the database and in the storage following the steps in https://firebase.google.com/docs/.

Here's the [8 min tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0ScnHJi8WY&t=33s).

After selecting the picture and write the title and description, I click the submit Button, then this error appears in the console:

```
 W/DynamiteModule: Failed to retrieve remote module version.
 W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via fast   routecom.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: Failed to connect to   dynamite module ContentResolver.
 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 9877470
 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.
 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module  com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module   com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0
  E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                         com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                             at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/UploadTask: Unable to create a network request from metadata
               android.os.RemoteException
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                   at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                  at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.<init>(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbre.zzj(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzaaN(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/EGL_emulation: tid 2710: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x8b8cd120, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

My java class

```
 public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton mSlectImage;
private EditText mPostTittle;
private EditText mPostDesc;

private Button SubmitButton;
private Uri mImageUri= null;

private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST=1;
private StorageReference mStorage;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mPostTittle=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.CreatePost_title);
    mPostDesc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.CreatePost_description);
    SubmitButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Publicar_button);
    mProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);

    mSlectImage=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mSlectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
    SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startPosting();
        }
    });
}

private void startPosting() {

    mProgress.setMessage("Posting to Blog...");
    mProgress.show();

    String title_val= mPostTittle.getText().toString().trim();
    String desc_val= mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val)&& mImageUri!=null){
        StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child("Blog_images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                mProgress.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        mImageUri=data.getData();
        mSlectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
    }

}
}
```

The layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_post"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.social.socialpart.socialpart.PostActivity">


  <ImageButton
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/post"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

  <EditText
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="title"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/CreatePost_title" />

  <EditText
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Description"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CreatePost_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/CreatePost_description" />

  <Button
    android:text="Submit post"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Publicar_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: you have to first check google play service version is match with build version if not then you to show pop up for update play service .

Comment: Have you tried to upload using storageRef.putBytes()?

Comment: These are some of my dependencies:  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'

Comment: i tried with 10.0.1 also